# Add existing database schema to JasperServer Installation

Tags: database, tomcat, jasperserver

I just installed Windows version of JasperServe and in the script it automatically created two databases (sugarcrm and foodmart) everything works fine. Now I would like to add my own database schema with existing tables and data. I tried to find example how to add existing database but had no luck so far. Is there any examples or tutorials how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do in the ui or create new ResourceDescriptor and make it's type as DataSource